# Passing generics into Promise like Promise<T>?

Tags: json, typescript, generics, promise

I have the following function:

```
class RestService {
    public async get<T>(func: string): Promise<T> {
        var toRet = {};
        await fetch(EndPoint + func)
        .then(response => response.json() as Promise<T>)
        .then(data => {
            toRet = data;
        })
        .catch(e => {
        });

        return toRet as T;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but the response I get in 'data' is ALWAYS a generic object.

For example I might have a model like so:

```
class Model
{
   string name;
}
```

and call the function like so:

```
get<Model>("getmodel")
```

The response is ALWAYS a generic object that looks like:

```
{name:"some name"}
```

From my understanding generics are supported in Typescript and Promise takes in variable types, my only thought is that I can't pass a generic into a generic?

Comment: If the response if always a Model, then the method shouldn't be generic, and its return type should be `Promise<Model>`. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: well the response from the endpoint is a json object, the model simply matches the json objects fields. I assume Promise<T> where T is the class would autopopulate an instance of the class with the json values.

Comment: So I might make a call to get like get<AnotherModel> and expect a return type of 'AnotherModel' but I get back an 'object' with fields matching the variable declarations in 'AnotherModel'...

Comment: No, it won't do that. response.json() simply deserializes the JSON to a POJO. It doesn't know and care about the concrete generc type. And `toRet as T` simply tells the TypeScript compiler: "trust me, the object is of type T, I know what I'm doing".

Comment: TypeScript is *purely compile time*, there's no runtime casting/conversion unless *you explicitly write it*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a better way to write it would be this way.

```js
class RestService {
    public async get<T>(func: string): Promise<T | void> {
        return await fetch('' + func)
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<T>)
            .then(data => {
                return data;
            })
            .catch(e => {
            });

    }
}
```

You can see it in the playground too at this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20RestService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20async%20get%3CT%3E(func%3A%20string)%3A%20Promise%3CT%20%7C%20void%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20await%20fetch(''%20%2B%20func)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(response%20%3D%3E%20response.json()%20as%20Promise%3CT%3E)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(data%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20data%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.catch(e%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

This way you don't have to overwrite any types and the compiler can figure out everything on it's own.

The return type is now `Promise<T | void>` because the `catch` function doesn't return anything. You could have something else or nothing depending what you do in case of an error.

Typescript will not transform the `data` object to match the `T` type you give in automatically.

If for example you call the method with `get<AnotherModel>('modelEndpoint')` but the endpoint returns `Model`. While the type at build time will say you should expect an object of type `AnotherModel` at runtime the object will in fact be of type `Model`.

This isn't clear from the question but maybe your issue is with the fact that the `data` is of type T instead of the `Promise<T>` that you return in the previous `then` callback.

If that is the case, that's because any Promise sent as a callback to the `then` function is resolved first before the outer `then` is called.

That means your code is equivalent to.

```js
.then(response => response.json().then((data) => data as T))
.then(data => {
   return data;
})
```

It's just that the Promise api will just take care of that for you.

If you want to learn more about the pitfalls of Promises in Javascript this [post](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) is quite good.